# Understanding and parsing FABMaster ASCII transfer format (.fatf) file

Tags: c#, parsing, data-structures, cad, fileparsing

How can I parse a `.fatf` or `.asc` (FABMaster ASCII transfer format).
Does any documentation exist for the file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a mail to FABMaster and they sent the official documentation, which describes the file structure. Now I can go on parsing the files with Antlr.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting sending them email - which contact did you use?